# How to concatenate multiple MigraDoc documents into one

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

There is sample code on how to add multiple Pdf documents into one in the [docs](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx). But I want to combine multiple MigraDoc documents into one.

The code I have so far is:

```
    private void GeneratePdfDocument(IEnumerable<Document> parts, string fileName)
    {
        using (var outputDocument = new PdfDocument())
        {
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                var renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(false, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);

                renderer.Document = part;

                renderer.RenderDocument();

                var pdfPart = renderer.PdfDocument;

                for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < pdfPart.PageCount; pageIndex++)
                {
                    outputDocument.AddPage(pdfPart.Pages[pageIndex]);
                }
            }

            // create the PDF
            outputDocument.Save(fileName);
        }
    }
```

But on `AddPage`, I get an `System.InvalidOperationException`:

```
A PDF document must be opened with PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import to import pages from it.
```

A solution would be to create each `Document` part as separate PDF, then combine all of them into a single PDF file, but not all parts will require a whole page.

*EDIT:*
I tried also the following approach:

```
            var combineDocument = new Document();
            foreach (var part in parts)
            {
                //for(var styleIndex = 0; styleIndex < part.Styles.Count; styleIndex++)
                //{
                //    combineDocument.Add(part.Styles[styleIndex]);
                //}

                for(var sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < part.Sections.Count; sectionIndex++)
                {
                    var section = part.Sections[sectionIndex].Clone();
                    combineDocument.Add(section);
                }
            }
```

The idea was to copy the sections of each `Document` into the `combineDocument` instance, but I was not able to retrieve the `Style` instances and the result was not as expected.

**Question:**
Is it possible to combine MigraDoc `Document` instances into one document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer elements of one MigraDoc `Document` into another, try the `Clone()` method of the element you want to transfer. This can also be used to re-use elements within the same document.
To do this, you have to iterate through all the document elements you want to copy and call `Clone()` for each and call `Add` for the receiving `Document` passing the cloned object as a parameter.

To work around the PDFsharp exception shown in the original question you could save the `PdfDocument` into a `MemoryStream` and open it again using `PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import`.

The solution I would prefer: Write methods that create MigraDoc `Document`s or their parts. Call those methods twice - once to create one big document, once to create several small documents. Thus you avoid cloning and saving/reading.

Comment: I'm already preparing the preferred solution, so each part is created as a MigraDoc `Document` separately, but the question is: How can I create a single ´PDF´ out of them?

Comment: Do not create each part as a separate `Document`, instead write routines that get a `Document` as a parameter and add their content. Then you can easily get separate documents with one aspect per document, or one big document that contains all aspects (maybe with a table of contents). - The other option is iterating through the small documents you have and call `Clone()` to add each element to another document.